# Can I have a generic type which contains a subsection of other types?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have several interfaces which always have a `field` member in common which itself always has one `body` field but can have also other fields.

I want to implement a generic abstract class with `T` which represents this subsections of all interfaces so that the abstract class can implement function which can access `fields.body` of this type.

Here is an example:

```
interface SomeInterface{
    title:string;
    fields: {
        title: { "en-US": string };
        body: { "en-US": any };
        some:{inter:string};
        different:string;
    }
}

interface SimilarbutNotSameInterface{
    description:string;
    fields: {
        title: { "en-US": string };
        body: { "en-US": any };
        similar:number;
        not:string;
    }
}

abstract class Manipulator<T>{
    abstract allInterfaces:T;
    
     Manipulator(): T {
         SomeOtherfunction(this.allInterfaces.fields.body["en-US"]);
        return this.allInterfaces;
    }
    
}
```

Is this possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for:

```
interface AbstractStructure {
  fields: Array<{
    body: unknown;
  }>
}

interface Structure1 extends AbstractStructure {
  fields: Array<{
    body: unknown;
    property1: string;
  }>
}


interface Structure2 extends AbstractStructure {
  fields: Array<{
    body: unknown;
    property2: string;
  }>
}

abstract class AbstractManipulator<T extends AbstractStructure> {
  abstract structures: T[];

  manipulate(): T[] {
    // We can safely access this property since it is present on AbstractStructure type     
    console.log(this.structures[0].fields[0].body);     
    return this.structures;
  }
}
```

This way `AbstractManipulator` will work with interface as long it extends `AbstractStructure`, which defines your desired fields.

Comment: yep that works, thanks